# My Ble device automatically disconnect after some time while performing write and read operation continuously using Rxbleandroid

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, rx-android

```
onClientConnectionState() - status=8 clientIf=9 device=FB:F8:78:28:A7:XX
05-29 11:04:20.504 18770-19733/com.aggrowth.guardian D/firmware update error: GATT exception from MAC address FB:F8:78:28:A7:32, status 133, type BleGattOperation{description='CHARACTERISTIC_READ'}. (Look up status 0x85 here https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/bluetooth/bluedroid/+/android-5.1.0_r1/stack/include/gatt_api.h)
05-29 11:04:20.505 18770-19276/com.aggrowth.guardian D/BluetoothGatt: readRssi() - device: FB:F8:78:28:A7:XX
05-29 11:04:20.507 3976-3991/? D/BtGatt.GattService: readRemoteRssi() - address=FB:F8:78:28:A7:XX
05-29 11:04:20.511 3976-4113/? E/BluetoothRemoteDevices: aclStateChangeCallback: State:DisConnected to Device:FB:F8:78:28:A7:XX
05-29 11:04:20.513 18770-18786/com.aggrowth.guardian D/guardian: Unsubscribing from connection attempt
05-29 11:04:20.518 18770-19276/com.aggrowth.guardian D/BluetoothManager: getConnectionState()
    getConnectedDevices
05-29 11:04:20.521 3976-4113/? D/BluetoothUtils: getBtEnabledContainers(): btContainers = []
05-29 11:04:20.524 4035-4220/? D/BluetoothEventManager: onReceive :: getAction = android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED
05-29 11:04:20.525 3976-4113/? W/bt_btif: btif_dm_upstreams_cback  ev: BTA_DM_BUSY_LEVEL_EVT
05-29 11:04:20.529 18770-19276/com.aggrowth.guardian D/BluetoothGatt: close()
05-29 11:04:20.531 18770-19276/com.aggrowth.guardian D/BluetoothGatt: unregisterApp() - mClientIf=9
05-29 11:04:20.533 3976-4537/? D/BtGatt.GattService: unregisterClient() - clientIf=9
05-29 11:04:20.537 18770-19733/com.aggrowth.guardian D/bluetooth: Failed to read RSSI
    com.polidea.rxandroidble.exceptions.BleDisconnectedException: Disconnected from FB:F8:78:28:A7:32
        at com.polidea.rxandroidble.internal.connection.RxBleGattCallback$2.onConnectionStateChange(RxBleGattCallback.java:76)
        at android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt$1.onClientConnectionState(BluetoothGatt.java:228)
        at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGattCallback$Stub.onTransact(IBluetoothGattCallback.java:70)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:573)
```

Comment: I have tried every solution adding delays and set latency mode but nothing worked out. Can anyone tell me what is going on here and it works fine on Lolipop device but it does not work at all on above device. Is there any restriction that device automatically disconnects after sometimes?

Comment: Later on, I found out it was BLE device who was automatically disconnected as there was a timeout set on the firmware side.